# 2018 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Home Improvement Stack Exchange's [fourth moderator election](https://diy.stackexchange.com/election/4) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the new moderator is:

[image: Michael Karas]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please join me in thanking Tester101 who will be stepping down as moderator.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/election/4), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5176108051857408/0).

Comment: Congrats and good luck to the new moderator.

Answer (score 2):

Congrats to Michael and Machavity I am just sorry there could be only one winner. I have seen both of your work and know you will perform in the best interests of the site.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If the implied question is "What do you think about the results of the 2018 community moderator election?", the answer is "Very nice."

Congrats Michael. Now put something in your profile and get to work. :)